# Can I make a path like that

Tags: java, servlets

Hello guys I a class like that:

```
@Path("infected")

public class Resource{

     @GET
    @Path("city/{infected}")
    public Response selectInfectadosCiudad(@PathParam("infected") String nombre){
    ...}
}
```

But when I try to go to .../infected/city/123 for example it gives me a 404, so I suppose that you can't call city/{infected} I mean you cant use city/ before the Pathparam am I correct?

Comment: Try /city/{infected} instead

Comment: not working, already tried bru

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to add '/' before the path

```
@Path("/infected")

public class Resource{

@GET
@Path("/city/{infected}")
public Response selectInfectadosCiudad(@PathParam("infected") String nombre){
...}
}
```

I'm not sure if this will work or not but try it

Comment: Then try to change the  name of the path variable itself to make sure that this is the thing that causes the problem in the first place

Comment: If you are using spring change the annotation to @PathVariable

Comment: The path of the class and all the functions there are working, including the one who has a variable path like {infected}

Comment: I tried this locally and  it is working  @RestController
 @RequestMapping("/api")
 class TestEndPoint{
  @GetMapping("/get-name/{api}")
  public ResponseEntity<String> s(@PathVariable String api){
   return ResponseEntity.ok("OOOOOOOOOOKKKKKKKKK");
   
  }
 }